# Javascript/Jquery-How to check if a function returns any value at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

Is there a way to check if a function returns ANY value at all.
So for example:

```
if(loop(value) --returns a value--) { 
    //do something
}

function loop(param) {
    if (param == 'string') {
        return 'anything';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions that don't return an object or primitive type return undefined. Check for undefined:

```
if(typeof loop(param) === 'undefined') {
    //do error stuff
}
```

Comment: for other viewers do   if( (typeof loop(param) ) === 'undefined') {
    //do error stuff
}    extra () important

Comment: if ( loop(param) === undefined ) {} // Works like in the answer and is "better".

Comment: How can I discriminate between a function which didn't return anything (e.g.: `function a() {} var ret = a(); // typeof ret === "undefined"`) and a function which explicitly returned undefined (e.g.: `function a() { return void 0; // Returns undefined explicitly } var ret = a(); // typeof ret === "undefined"`)? Is there a way to know (from the caller side) that a function has returned through a return statement instead of implicitly? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A function with no `return` will return `undefined`. You can check for that.

However, a `return undefined` in the function body will also return `undefined` (obviously).

Comment: How to differentiate the two cases (implicit `undefined` return and explicit `return undefined`) from the caller side?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
if(loop(param) === undefined){}
```

That will work everytime with one exception, if your function return `undefined`, it will enter in the loop. I mean, it return something but it is undefined...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with the output of your function in the case it returns something, first pass it to a variable and then check if the type of that variable is `"undefined"`.

---

#### Demo

```js
testme("I'm a string");
testme(5);

function testme(value) {
  var result = loop(value);
  if(typeof result !== "undefined") { 
    console.log("\"" + value + "\" --> \"" + result + "\"");
  } else {
    console.warn(value + " --> " + value + " is not a string");
  }

  function loop(param) {
    if (typeof param === "string") {
      return "anything";
    }
  }
}
```